# Make additional asynchronous call to UserManager<T> after pagination

Tags: c#, linq, asynchronous, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I have a LINQ query that gets the results from a database with filtering and pagination and that maps the result to the `PaginatedList<T>`.

```
var bookReservationList = await _dbContext.BookReservations
    .Include(x => x.Books).Select(
    book => new BookRequestViewModel
    {

        Author = book.Books.Author

    }).PaginatedListAsync(pageNumber, pageSize);
```

Now with the result obtained from the `bookReservationList` in the above LINQ query, I wanted to call the `GetUserEmailAsync` to get the

`Requester = await _identityService.GetUserEmailAsync(book.RequesterId)`, which is the call to `UserManager<T>`

**I have been trying in this way but I am failing:** to map the result to Task<PaginatedList>

```
    var res = bookReservationList.Items.Select(async y => new BookRequestViewModel
    {
        Requester = await _identityService.GetUserEmailAsync(y.RequesterId);

    });
```

**PaginatedListAsync**

```
public static Task<PaginatedList<TDestination>> PaginatedListAsync<TDestination>(this IQueryable<TDestination> queryable, int pageNumber, int pageSize)
{
    return PaginatedList<TDestination>.CreateAsync(queryable, pageNumber, pageSize);
}
```

**PaginatedList**

```
public class PaginatedList<T>
{
    public List<T> Items { get; }
    public int PageIndex { get; }
    public int TotalPages { get; }
    public int TotalCount { get; }

    public PaginatedList(List<T> items, int count, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        PageIndex = pageIndex;
        TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(count / (double)pageSize);
        TotalCount = count;
        Items = items;
    }

    public bool HasPreviousPage => PageIndex > 1;

    public bool HasNextPage => PageIndex < TotalPages;

    public static async Task<PaginatedList<T>> CreateAsync(IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        var count = await source.CountAsync();
        var items = await source.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();

        return new PaginatedList<T>(items, count, pageIndex, pageSize);
    }
}
```

The implementation of `GetUserEmailAsync` is done as:

```
public interface IIdentityService
{
    Task<string> GetUserEmailAsync(string userId);
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class BookRequestViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Requester { get; set; }
    public string RequesterId { get; set; }
    public DateTime RequestDate { get; set; }
}
```

Basically, I want to return the result as

`Task<PaginatedList<BookRequestViewModel>> GetRequestedBookList(int pageNumber, int pageSize);` but failing to do so.

Comment: `but failing to do so.` What specifically is failing?

Comment: I can't map the result obtained after the second async call to return `Task<PaginatedList<BookRequestViewModel>> `.

Comment: So you have some kind of `IdentityDbContext`? IMHO skip the `UserManager`, just define the navigation from book to user in your model, then select the user email in your query.

Comment: Yes, I have been using the IdentityDbContext. But, as you said there is no navigation from the book to the user, so I had to make a call using UserManager. And due to my project structure, I don't have access to `ApplicationUser` from the entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do that with LINQ. You have to use `foreach`

```cs
foreach (y in bookReservationList.Items)
{
    y.Requester = await _identityService.GetUserEmailAsync(y.RequesterId);
}
```